# Conway's Version of the Axiom of Regularity

Tags: set-theory

In the Appendix to Part Zero of *On Numbers and Games,* John Horton Conway gives what he says is an equivalent version of the axiom of regularity in ZF.

> If $P$ is a proposition that holds of a set $x$ whenever it holds for all members of $x$, then $P$ holds for every set.

This inductive principle is certainly more intuitive than what Conway calls "the peculiarly opaque form" of the axiom of regularity:

> Every nonempty Class [sic] $X$ has some member disjoint from X.

I should mention that, although Conway speaks of ZF, he allows proper classes.  In fact, the capitalization of "Class" in the statement of the axiom of regularity indicates that $X$ may be a proper class.

I've been trying to show the equivalence.

One direction is easy.  Suppose that the axiom of regularity holds, and let $P$ be a proposition with the property above.  Let $Y=\{x|\neg P(x)\}$  By the axiom of regularity, $\exists y\in Y(y\cap Y=\emptyset)$  But then all the members of $y$ satisfy $P$ and $y$ does not satisfy $P$, contradiction.

For the other direction, assume that Conway's version holds, and let $$
P(x)=x=\emptyset \vee \exists a\in x(a\cap x = \emptyset)$$  I need to show that if $P(y)$ is true for all $y\in x$ then $P(x)$ is true. So, $\forall y\in x(\exists z\in x\cap y),$ and we have $z \in y \in x$ However, $z\in x$ so we can apply the same argument repeatedly to get an infinite descending sequence $\dots \in z \in y \in x$ which I know is prohibited by the axiom of regularity, but I don't see how to use in this situation.

Can you help me to complete the proof, or show me a line that succeeds if this approach is hopeless?

Comment: "Conway's version" is better known as $\in$-induction. (And I don't think that attributing this to Conway is historically correct either.)

Comment: I didn't attribute it to Conway.  I said he gives it in the Appendix to Part Zero of *On Numbers and Games*  Look it up if you don't believe me.

Comment: Look at the title of your question.

Comment: That's just an informal title.  You are making too much of this.  I have nothing more to say on this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply Conway's version with $P(x)$ being the property "every Class $A$ that has $x$ as an element also has an element $y$ such that $y\cap A=\varnothing$.

Comment: Thank you.  That seems so simple, but I doubt that I would ever have thought of it myself.